# Accessing rails model through rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I was looking to test a method I had created in my "Herd" model. The methods called "safely_assign_herd_usages". I understand how to instantiate a herd e.g. H = Herd.last However, I'm struggling to gain access to the method to test the lines of code within it. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you literally typed `H=Herd.last` then it should be `h=Herd.last` (note lowercase 'h'). Uppercase designates constants in Ruby

Comment: What is the error you get on the console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger in the method you want to test.

[`debug`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html) is the standard option.

```rb
require 'debug'

def safely_assign_herd_usages
  ...
  binding.break # will interrupt here
  ...
end
```

Then in your Rails console, trigger the method to get to the breakpoint:

```rb
$ Herd.first.safely_assign_herd_usages
```

Now the console will load up the method in question and give you an interactive console at that specific spot.